# Is there a programmatic way to edit a Brightcove video's reference ID?

Tags: json, api, http, brightcove

The example on the Brightcove site provides the JSON needed to update tags for a particular video in my library:

```
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"123456",
  "shortDescription":"vidDesc","Name":"vidName","startDate":1392912992000,
  "endDate":null,"tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]},"token":"someToken.."}}
```

I've tried this, and it works.

But when I try to post something similar but with an updated reference ID, like this:

```
{"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"123456",
  "shortDescription":"vidDesc","Name":"vidName","startDate":1392912992000,
  "endDate":null,"referenceId":"newReferenceId","token":"someToken.."}}
```

I get this error back from the service:

```
{"error": {"name":"MissingJSONError","message":"Could not find JSON-RPC.",
  "code":211}, "result": null, "id": null}
```

I've tried passing it as `ref` as well - no dice.  Does anyone know if it's possible to update this value via any means other than Brightcove's web portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're sending the JSON as form data rather than in the post body.

e.g. with curl,

```
curl -F 'json={"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"123456789","referenceId":"newrefid"},"token":"myToken"}}' https://api.brightcove.com/services/post
```

Comment: If your JSON is in a file, you must use `curl -F 'json=<some.json' https://api.brightcove.com/services/post`. Note the `<` instead of the usual `@`. Reference [CURL -F](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)